# How to instantiate multiple lists to the same value, though distinct in memory?

Tags: python, list, memory

I need to declare three different lists to (initially) the same value:

```
a = b = c = ["Ralph"]
```

But when I append to just "a":

```
a.append("Wiggum")
```

the following results are generated:

```
print a, b, c
>>["Ralph", "Wiggum"] ["Ralph", "Wiggum"] ["Ralph", "Wiggum"]
```

What I need is:

```
print a, b, c
>>["Ralph", "Wiggum"] ["Ralph"] ["Ralph"]
```

I know if I make use of [copy.copy()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) or instantiate a new list, that will create a new space in memory.  But I am looking for a short (preferably one line) way similar to a=b=c that generates distinct lists.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want a one-liner, you can do something like this:

```
a, b, c = (["Ralph"] for _ in range(3))
```

But frankly, if it's a small list like the example, I'd simply make it obvious:

```
a, b, c = ["Ralph"], ["Ralph"], ["Ralph"]
```

Comment: But for instances with a lot of lists to declare, ouch.  The list comprehension is neato, though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use generator and tuple unpack.

```
a, b, c = (["Ralph"] for _ in range(3))
```

You want different variables bind to different mutable objects. It must create independent mutable object for each variable.

But you can bind different variables to single immutable objects. After you modify one variable of those, You will bind that variable to a new immutable object. For example:

```
>>> a, b, c = ("Ralph", )
>>> a += ("Wiggum", )
>>> a
("Ralph", "Wiggum")
>>> b
("Ralph",)
>>> c
("Ralph",)
```

Check this [link](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=x%20%3D%20y%20%3D%20z%20%3D%20%5B%22Ralph%22%5D%0Ax.append%28%22Wiggum%22%29%0A%0Ai,%20j,%20k%20%3D%20%28%5B%22Ralph%22%5D%20for%20_%20in%20range%283%29%29%0Ai.append%28%22Wiggum%22%29%0A%0Aa%20%3D%20b%20%3D%20c%20%3D%20%28%22Ralph%22,%20%29%0Aa%20%2B%3D%20%28%22Wiggum%22,%20%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=18&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)